# Shared classes and functionality between c# and c++

Tags: c#, c++, class, dll, methods

I have a C# WinForm project which edits stuff and saves it in a file using several classes that are stored directly as bytes. I had another C# project (Console) that used those same classes to read the previous saved data and work with it. In order not to have functionalities duplicated, and because this data structure is frequently changing, I kept these classes in a separate DLL that both projects included.

Now, however, I need that functionality to be used natively in C++, but of course I cannot simply include that same DLL in the project. I have tried to get an idea of how to work around that but I think I am mixing several concepts...

Is there any solution that allowed me to instantiate classes from that library, read their data and call their methods in both C# and C++ without the need of duplicating a lot of stuff?

The solutions I have (probably wrongly) considered include:

1- Keep the C# DLL, but allowing the COM interop and work with that. Then somehow create and maintain wrappers for C++.

2- Rewrite the DLL in C++ (it's still small, for now, so it's not a problem) and import it within C#. P/Invoke does not seem to work with member functions though, so I would still need to create a wrapper.

As a side note, the stored classes make use of C# Lists and Dictionaries. If there is a solution that works only with custom-generated classes, I wouldn't mind to create my own data structures.

Comment: Another option is to use [tag:c++-cli].

Comment: c++/cli approach does not seem very convincing to me, as I would still need to maintain both the library and a wrapper for each class within the library... Although if there's no straightforward solution I guess I'll have to go with it.